# change order of shipping services in checkout

Tags: commerce

I build two Shipping services in a drupal commerce shop. One with calculated rates. One with 0€ for pickup by the customer.
It looks like this:
[image]
But i would like to change the order and make shipping service with costs as default.
I tried to change the wight of the calculation rules, but without effect.
Is it true, that I need a module for this task?
It would be no problem, but I don't won't to overlook a easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's a pending feature request to make these orderable via the user interface, but in the meantime you're dependent on code to change their ordering. The hook to use is hook_commerce_shipping_collect_rates(), and what you need to do is alter the weight value of the line items in the $order->shipping_rates array.